# How to assign a list without changing the address?

Tags: python

I have a subroutine that is given a list which is used at another part in the program, and the subroutine is to modify that list.
In particular, it is supposed to trim the list.

Let's say the code looks like this so far:

```
class Foo:
    array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    
def modify(target, length):
    array = target.array
    array = array[0:length]

foo = Foo()
print(foo.array)
modify(foo, 3)
print(foo.array)
```

Executing this code will produce the output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

because the line `array = array[0:length]` creates a new list and the temporary variable `array` is then simply set to point to a new address.

However, I'd like to find some way in which `modify` actually changes the object.
Now for this code example, it would be a simple solution to add a line `target.array = array`. However, in my actual case, the actual class I am dealing with has a side effect for the setter that I want to avoid (I do something like that several times in a row, and each time would render some data which would show states in-between, and also complain about jagged data).

Now the thing is, I could rewrite this particular function into

```
def modify(target, length):
    array = target.array
    while(len(array)>length):
        array.pop(-1)
```

since `pop` doesn't change the address.

I could also write some helper method like

```
def copy_into(source: list, target: list)
```

that is then called like

```
copy_into(array[0:length], array)
```

This would be my workaround, but it doesn't strike me exactly as being elegant, or pythonic. And I'd like to know whether there is a standard way to assign without changing address in general.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: `object = Object()` is a **very** bad idea. `object` is a Python built-in. Don't do that. Pick any other name than `object`!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Just example code, but I can change the names if you like. Edit: Done.

Comment: Note also that in your class `array` is a class attribute but you're treating it as if it's an instance attribute.

Comment: @Samwise Didn't want to write a full `__init__` just for example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using slice assignment is one way to do this.  A simple example that doesn't involve a wrapper class (since it's irrelevant to the subject of the question and the class has other problems that muddy the discussion):

```
def truncate(array, length):
    array[:] = array[:length]

array = list(range(6))
print(array)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
truncate(array, 3)
print(array)  # [0, 1, 2]
```

When you assign to a list's `[:]` slice you're essentially saying "replace the list's entire *contents* with the RHS of the assignment".  The RHS expression can be a list, a list slice, or any other iterable.

Comment: Other options for mutating a list include `.clear()` and `.extend()`, so you could `clear()` the list to empty it and then `extend` it by the contents of another iterable.  But it's obviously simpler to just do it in one step.